# Order array depending on appearance in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Lets say I have 2 arrays of users.

```
[user1, user2, user3]

[user3]
```

Based on the second array, I want to sort the first array so that occurrences in the second array appear first in the first array.

So the result of the first array would be:

```
[user3, user1, user2]
```

I realise the simple way would be to iterate over the first array and populate an empty array, ordering it if the second array contains it, then merging the rest. The below is pseudo code and untested, but gives an idea of what I was thinking as a simple solution

```
return_array = []
array1.each do |a|
  if array2.include? a
    return_array.push array1.pop(a)
  end
end
return_array.merge array1
```

Is there any way to refine this? Built in rails or ruby methods for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use array intersection and array difference:

```
a&b + a-b
```

would give you what you're looking for.
The manual for intersection: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26
The manual for difference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D

Comment: Well, this obviously depends on which is `a` and which is `b` as the intersection operation is commutative and the difference isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
array2 + (array1 - array2)
```

Comment: This would leave you with all the elements of the second array, what's needed is the elements that appear in both first...

Comment: You're right, I just made the assumption that `array2` was a subset of `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
my_array2 = ['user3']
my_array2 + (my_array.sort - my_array2)
```